# How to get dynamically different type of datatype value in SQL server pivot table

Tags: sql-server, datetime, subquery, pivot, inner-join

I have this following table with header information:

```
InformationID  Name               DispalyName                         VAlueType
1              Occupation         Occupation                          Text 
3              Surgery            Surgery                             Header
4              SurgeryType        SurgeryType                         Text
5              SurgeryDate        SurgeryDate                         Datetime
8              Rehabilitation     Rehabilitation                      Header
9              RehabilitationPT   Rehabilitation Physiotherapist      Text
10             RehabilitationDate Rehabilitation Date                 DateTime
11             DischargeSession   Discharge Session Number            int
12             Height             Height                              decimal
13             Weight             Weight                              decimal

I have another table has all these rows values stored like this:

InfomationID  ClientID    TextValue          NumberValue     DateValue
1             XXXX        Programmer         null            null
4             XXXX        Left knee surgery  null            null
5             XXXX        null               null            2016-08-01 01:00:00
11            XXXX        null               6               null
12            XXXX        null               164.592         null
```

Now I need to get those in a sub-query with where ClientID = XXXX
Part of result would be something following:

```
CFname| CLname| Occupation| SurgeryType      | SurgeryDate| DischargeSession
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CFName| CLname| Programmer| Left knee surgery| 2016-08-01 | 6
::::
::::
More records
```

Regards

Comment: Why is 6 the DischargeSession? There is nowhere near enough information to provide anything resembling an answer here. Why is that the surgery date and not some other date? Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ The reason you are struggling here is because you have an anti-pattern known as entity value attribute (EAV). It seems so cool but often it is far too painful to work with.

Answer (score 0):

you would just need to convert the number and date values to varchar.. you can use coalesce to get the first non null value.

your pivot would looks something like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
        SELECT  c.CFName,
                c.CLName,
                fh.Name,
                COALESCE(fv.TextValue, 
                         CAST(fv.NumberValue AS VARCHAR(50)), -- convert numbers to text
                         CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fv.DateValue, 101) AS DynamicValue -- convert date to text 
                                                                                 -- increase varchar length for time
                                                                                 -- or 101 for different format
        FROM    ClientInfo c
        JOIN    FieldValues fv ON c.ClientID = fv.ClientID
        JOIN    FieldHeaders fh ON fh.InformationID = fv.InformationID
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(DynamicValue)
    FOR fh.Name IN ([Occupation], [SurgeryType], [SurgeryDate], [DischargeSession])
) p
```

to do this dynamically you would need to build your sql and inject the pivot columns into the sql by selecting the values into a nvarchar using STUFF(FOR XML)

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = STUFF((
                        SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME(Name)
                        FROM    FieldHeaders
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, 0)
SET     @Sql = N'
    SELECT  *
    FROM (
            SELECT  c.CFName,
                    c.CLName,
                    fh.Name,
                    COALESCE(fv.TextValue, 
                             CAST(fv.NumberValue AS VARCHAR(50)), -- convert numbers to text
                             CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), fv.DateValue, 101) AS DynamicValue -- convert date to text 
                                                                                     -- increase varchar length for time
                                                                                     -- or 101 for different format
            FROM    ClientInfo c
            JOIN    FieldValues fv ON c.ClientID = fv.ClientID
            JOIN    FieldHeaders fh ON fh.InformationID = fv.InformationID
    ) t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(DynamicValue)
        FOR fh.Name IN (' + @Columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Needed to do the convert data. Great help.